# TFN validation code with rendering parts not working - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I need to make a straight Reactjs TFN validator and because I'm very new to Javascript, I'm having a lot of trouble. I've tried countless fixes but none have worked with the integration standards that I need to abide by. I'm sure I've just made a dumb mistake but I can't see it. If anyone wants to spend 10 minutes looking at what I've written and giving feedback, I'd really appreciate it and if someone does figure out how to get it working, I'm sure anyone else who could use this will appreciate. Thanks!

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'


export function TfnForm(props) {
    
    const [tfnvalue,settfnvalue] = useState("");
    const [success, setsuccess] = useState(false)
    var tfnconf = false;
    var sum = 0;
    console.log(tfnconf,"initiate")


    const handleValidation = validate => {
        setsuccess(current => !current)
    }


///return statements for render
    var doSuccess = function(message) {
        
        ('#result').addClass('bg-success').text(message).show();
    };
    var doError = function(message) {
        
        ('#result').addClass('bg-danger').text(message).show();
    };

///validation algorithm
    const validate = () => {
        
        if (tfnvalue.length === 9);
            sum = (tfnvalue[0]*1)
                    + (tfnvalue[1]*4)
                    + (tfnvalue[2]*3)
                    + (tfnvalue[3]*7)
                    + (tfnvalue[4]*5)
                    + (tfnvalue[5]*8)
                    + (tfnvalue[6]*6)
                    + (tfnvalue[7]*9)
                    + (tfnvalue[8]*10);
            sum = sum%11
            if (sum === 0) {
                return (
                    doSuccess("Valid Tax File Number")
                )
            }
            return (
                doError("Invalid TFN, check the digits.")
                )
            }
            
        
    
///rendering html
    return (
        
        <div className="container">
            <form id="tfn_validator">
                <h2>TFN Validator</h2>
                    <div className={success ? 'has-success':'has-error'}>
                        <label htmlFor="tfn" className="sr-only">TFN</label>
                        <input type="text" id="tfn" size="40" className="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter the TFN" autoComplete="off" onChange={v=>settfnvalue(v.currentTarget.value)} required autoFocus />
                 </div>
                    <br />
                <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="button" onClick={validate}>Validate</button>
                <br />
                
            </form>
            <br />
        </div>
    )}
```

Comment: also I know theres some jquery in there, I'm trying to work out a way to swap it for react. and again, thank you to anyone who helps.